# $f(1+x) = f(x)$ for all real $x$, $f$ is a polynomial and $f(5) = 11$. What is $f\large(\frac{15}{2}\large)$?

Tags: polynomials, gre-exam

I was looking through a GRE math subject test practice test ([here](http://www.wmich.edu/mathclub/files/GR8767.pdf)) and in particular I was confused regarding this question [image]

I chose E because I thought that (since the problem didn't specify) it could be an infinite polynomial that becomes the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = A \sin (x\pi)+11$, where $A$ can be anything.

The correct answer is apparently C. Is there a reason (other than my probably unwarranted assumption) that the answer HAS to be C?

Comment: An "infinite polynomial" is, by definition, not a polynomial. A polynomial has a degree.

Comment: Hint: $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is a polynomial, and it has infinitely many roots.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ isn't a constant polynomial then for every root $x_0$ of it $x_0+n$ is also a root for all $n$ and this contradicts the fundamental theorem of algebra. Conclude.

Comment: That's the right intuition, but the proof needs some elaboration, since the problem as stated does not guarantee a *real* root $x_0$, and $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ only.

Comment: It's only a slight modification-- if $f(a) = c$, then $g(x) = f(x) - c$ has infinitely many zeros, so it must be identically zero.

Comment: But this indicates you haven't read past the front of the question - the OP clearly seems to think power series are polynomials. The key to this question is: What was wrong about the OP's reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

It is C. You have the constant map because that is the only polynomial that will give you back f(x)=f(1+x)=f(2+x)... as a function value infinitely many times! Every other polynomial "goes somewhere" on the tail (plus or minus infinity).

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x^1 + \cdots + a_nx^n$$

$$f(x+1) = a_0 + a_1(x+1)^1 + \cdots + a_n(x+1)^n$$

It can be shown by induction that

$$f(x) = f(x+1) \to a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$$

Note that

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x^1 + \cdots$$

is not a polynomial

Comment: `f(x)=f(x+1) → a_1=a_2=⋯=a_n=0` That's equivalent to OP's problem, so you need to prove it, not just assert it.

Comment: @dxiv Edited: induction. Thanks!